# JSON.net Add new Property with the same name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to merge this two Json's in only one, a mean, Level B with several Applications items:

Json 1:

```
 {
   "Level A": {
                "Level B": {
                    "Application": [
                        {
                            "id": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Json 2:

```
  {
        "Level A": {
            "Level B": {
                "Application": [
                    {
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code:

```
_jsonMaster = JObject.Parse(jsonMaster);
_jsonApplication = JObject.Parse(jsonApplication);

JProperty newApplication = _jsonApplication["Level A"]["LevelB"].First as JProperty;

_jsonMaster["Level A]["Level B"].AddAfterSelf(newApplication);
```

This is my error:

An error ocurred while executing the JoinNewApplication: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty cannot have multiple values.

If not possible have two Properties with the same name?

Comment: Could that be because "Level B" is not an array?

Comment: The answer is *yes, it's not possible to have two properties with the same name*.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, you are right, I created a property with objects, in this way works